# How to make it so the year variable counts as a column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I currently have code to average the ratings of the movies by the year, but when it does this when I look at the shape it says I have 3 columns instead of 4 and I need the year to act as a column to do further analysis.

This is the code I currently have to create a mean based on the year:

```
year_rating=movie_ratings.groupby(['year']).agg(lambda x: x.unique().sum()/x.nunique())
```

The table output:

```
year  movieId         userId         rating

1874  148054.000000   76813.333333   3.000
1878  148048.000000   76404.818182   3.000
...             ...            ...     ...
2018  194400.452428   81183.849270   2.750
2019  203531.063508   80773.959827   2.750

[136 rows x 3 columns]
```

If there is a simpler way to take the average rating for each year I'm open to suggestions. I'm also looking for a way to make the column year an actual column as I get an error if I try to do linear regression.

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Comment: Use `as_index=False` in groupby

Comment: it looks like `year` is currently the index for the dataframe, you can reset the index with `df = df.reset_index()` and then use `year` as expected. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html